# Использование в ячейках таблицы hover

Tags: html, javascript, css

Короче говоря: есть картинка (умывальник), при наведении курсора он обрамляется в картинку "шестиугольник".
Как сделать?

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="http://www.santeri.su/files/photos/b5bfb5834c9e86b615a8f8d52d1014d5.jpg" onmouseover="this.src = 'http://www.rukodelie.by/06/r5043201.gif';" />
```

[**Пример.**](http://jsfiddle.net/6HsNb/)

Comment: Это супер! Дайте пожму Вашу руку! ))))

Comment: Ага, завтра.

Comment: немного доработали: http://jsfiddle.net/zRgF5/1/

Comment: прикольный ответ:) шестиугольник полностью закрывает умывальник при наведении мыши. Примерно так и у меня получается. Смешно!

Answer (score 0):

Нужны две картинки: умывальник простой и умывальник сложный. А затем - немного магии:

```
<img src="_умывальник_" onmouseover="this.src='_умывальник_рамка_';"  onmouseout="this.src='_умывальник_';" />
```

Есть еще много прикольных методов, но этот - самый простой.